# Convolution of two impulse responses with noise

Tags: exponential-function, convolution, noise

In short, I need help by creating a function describing a decaying process in time. I know

$$
h(t) = e ^ {xt} * e ^ {xt} = te^{xt} 
$$

I use * as the convolution sign. if then the exponential functions are modulated with a white noise sequence,

$$
h(t) = e ^ {xt}w(t) * e ^ {xt}w(t-t_1) = t^{0.5}e^{xt}w'(t) 
$$

Here w'(t) is a non-gaussian white noise sequence with the same statistical properties as white noise.

My question is can I do something similar when the decay terms in the exponential are different:
Without noise
$$
h(t) = e ^ {x_1t} * e ^ {x_2t} = (e^{x_1t} - e^{x_2t})/(x1-x2)
$$
With noise
$$
h(t) = e ^ {x_1t}w(t) * e ^ {x_2t}w(t-t_1) =  ??
$$
I hope my question is clear this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thought convolution of a white noise with a delayed version of it is an impulse.